# how to do search operation in custome listview with image

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-filterable

I am trying to set the search in a custom listview there is a run time error dont know why i followed one of the stack over flow post .here is what i m trying
activity code:

```
 private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> songarr = new ArrayList<>();
 private static final int EXT_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 2;
 private SearchAdapter adapte;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkReadStoragePermission();
    Songdata load = new Songdata();
    this.songarr = load.getPlayList(this);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            adapte.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
    adapte = new SearchAdapter(this, songarr);
    listView.setAdapter(adapte);
}
```

Adapter code

```
public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> songar;
private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> searchar;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Songfileinfo> songarr) {
    this.searchar = songarr;
    this.songar = songarr;
    this.context= context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return songar.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout llContainer;
    TextView tvName, tvPrice;
    CircleImageView circleImageView;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertview == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        holder.llContainer = (LinearLayout) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tryi1);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        holder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.circleImageView = (CircleImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        convertview.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvName.setText(songar.get(i).getTitle());
    holder.tvPrice.setText(songar.get(i).getAlbum());
    Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(songar.get(i).getAlbum_art()))
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .fitCenter()
            .error(R.drawable.music)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(holder.circleImageView);

    return convertview;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            searchar = (ArrayList<Songfileinfo>) results.values; // has the filtered values
            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            ArrayList<Songfileinfo> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Songfileinfo>();

            if (searchar == null) {
                searchar = new ArrayList<Songfileinfo>(songar); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

                           if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = searchar.size();
                results.values = searchar;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < searchar.size(); i++) {
                    String data = searchar.get(i).getTitle();
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(new Songfileinfo(searchar.get(i).getTitle(),searchar.get(i).getAlbum(),searchar.get(i).getAlbum_art()));
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

}

and songfile info class

```
public class Songfileinfo implements Parcelable{
private String title,album,artist,file_uri;
private String album_art;

public Songfileinfo(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    album = in.readString();
    artist = in.readString();
    file_uri = in.readString();
    album_art = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Songfileinfo> CREATOR = new Creator<Songfileinfo>() {
    @Override
    public Songfileinfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Songfileinfo(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Songfileinfo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Songfileinfo[size];
    }
};

public Songfileinfo(String album_art,String title,String album) {
    this.album=album;
    this.album_art=album_art;
    this.title=title;
}

public Songfileinfo() {

}
```

the app is fine it display the listview correctly but when i click the edit text it crashes with error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter beatbox.neelay.searchtest.SearchAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
                  at beatbox.neelay.searchtest.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:47)
                  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8000)
                  at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8062)
                  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10185)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1033)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:559)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:492)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:34)
                  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:685)
                  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:445)
                  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:340)
                  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

any idea where i m doing wrong ??

Comment: Can you post the full code of the first snippet??

Answer (score 0):

You are apply filter on a null object

```
adapte.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
```

it should be

```
adapte = new SearchAdapter(this, songarr);
```

not

```
BaseAdapter adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, songarr);
```

As you have already defined `SearchAdapter adapte` as global

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize **adapte**, I guess you dont need

```
BaseAdapter adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, songarr);
```

then inside filter method of your adpapter, you have to call **notifyDatasetChanged** to reflect the filtered values.

Comment: I called  notify datasetchanged in the filter method but it is not filtering the data

Comment: i added adapte.notifyDatasetChanged() but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

By following one of the youtube video i am able to get the data

Adapter class code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> display;
private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> searcharr;
CustomFilter customFilter;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Songfileinfo> songarr) {
    this.context = context;
    this.display = songarr;
    this.searcharr = songarr;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return display.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return display.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return display.indexOf(getItem(pos));
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);

    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    textView.setText(display.get(pos).getTitle());
    textView1.setText(display.get(pos).getAlbum());
    Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(display.get(pos).getAlbum_art()))
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .fitCenter()
            .error(R.drawable.music)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(circleImageView);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (customFilter==null){
        customFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return customFilter;
}


class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {
            charSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<Songfileinfo> filter = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < searcharr.size(); i++) {
                if (searcharr.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)) {
                    Songfileinfo songfileinfo = new Songfileinfo(searcharr.get(i).getTitle(), searcharr.get(i).getAlbum(), searcharr.get(i).getAlbum_art());
                    filter.add(songfileinfo);
                }
            }
            filterResults.count = filter.size();
            filterResults.values = filter;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = searcharr.size();
            filterResults.values = searcharr;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        display = (ArrayList<Songfileinfo>) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and my activity class code

```
 private ArrayList<Songfileinfo> songarr = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkReadStoragePermission();
    Songdata load = new Songdata();
    this.songarr = load.getPlayList(this);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview);
    final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, songarr);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {



            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            customAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

private ArrayList<Songfileinfo>getPlaylist(){
    ArrayList<Songfileinfo>  newlist =new ArrayList<Songfileinfo>();
    Songfileinfo songfileinfo;
    for (int i =0;i<songarr.size();i++){

        songfileinfo =new Songfileinfo(songarr.get(i).getTitle(),songarr.get(i).getAlbum_art(),songarr.get(i).getAlbum());
        newlist.add(songfileinfo);
    }
    return newlist;
}
```

Hope this will help some one in future